# How does ski binding height affect skiing off-piste?

Tags: skiing, ski-bindings

I have [this binding](http://www.diamir.com/en/product/diamir-freeride-pro/) with height of 39 mm. I like to freeride and do jumps. I would like to know what are pros and cons of high and low ski bindings and how particularly the height affects ability to control ski while jumping or freeriding.

Comment: As far as I know the only benefit is for carving. The higher your boot is off of your ski, the more you can carve before your boot makes contact with the ground.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This dimension is know as the *binding stack height* (as well as *binding stand height*) and can be both beneficial and detrimental:

- **On piste / carving / racing**: a larger stack height is generally perceived as beneficial---the FIS even passed a regulation limiting it to 50mm after the thickness of binding plates started getting out of hand. The main benefits are more leverage over the edge of the skis and the ability to tip the ski further on edge without boot/snow interference.
- **Off piste / powder / park**: a smaller stack height is generally seen as beneficial. Being closer to the ski provides more stability over uneven terrain (imagine trying to ski wearing stilts). A smaller stack height can sometimes indicate a lighter setup--less material raising your boot off the ski (obviously varies from binding to binding). A smaller stack height also gets you those last couple millimeters closer to face shots in powder =P

And of course, we can't neglect looking taller in the lift line or group photos!

Comment: Thanks for the keyword "binding stack height", that also helped me to look it up further.

Comment: I have a pair of race skis that had a serious spacer under the bindings. I thought that if I took it out I could save some weight on my skis, that's when I discovered they weight virtually nothing.

Comment: @PeterKvačkaj You may be interested to know that the stack height on your bindings is virtually zero. You Binding hasn't been raised for on-piste performance. It's up higher than the average binding because of the mechanical nature of being for alpine climbing.

Comment: @ShemSeger Its higher because of the requirement to have a bar underneath the foot. Even then you can have something like the [Marker Duke](http://marker.net/products/bindings/duke-16-epf.html) bindings that are lower. Of course you aren't going to get a ski crampon underneath the Dukes....

Comment: @Erik That's what I said. 'The mechanical nature' of the binding, vis–à–vis other step-in alpine touring bindings with DIN settings that have a full shank under the boot. I have Marker Tour F12's on my skis, and yes they do make crampons for them and the duke's: https://www.mec.ca/en/product/5026-012/Duke-F12-Ski-Crampons

Comment: @Erik It's a funny coincidence that you would mention the Markers, which I ride with, and the question is about Diamir bindings, which my brother skis with. I'm very familiar with both sets of bindings. I've spent hours watching the heels of Diamir bindings go up, and down, listening to the squeaking sound they make.

Comment: @ShemSeger That's what I get for assuming! :) I haven't spent much time around the Dukes or the Fritschi bindings. Growing up I toured with 3 pin bindings and then transitioned to tech bindings. When I initially read your comment I thought you were saying that all AT bindings required the boot to be so high above the ski. Now I can see you were talking about the design of the Fritschi binding in particular.

Comment: @Erik, No, telemarks and Dynafits for example have zero stack height. The first "AT" bindings were an adapter you stuck into your downhill ski bindings. Those had a huge stack height. http://www.earnyourturns.com/13279/review-backcountry-adaptor-alpine-trekker/

Comment: @ShemSeger yeah my roommate in Jackson Hole had a pair of those. There were all kinds of different bindings before the AlpineTrekker though that were used for a time. Lou Dawson's site has a [binding museum](https://www.wildsnow.com/backcountry-skiing-history/binding-museum-backcountry-skiing/). As a matter of fact since you're a fan, Marker had [an AT binding in 1982](https://www.wildsnow.com/backcountry-skiing-history/binding-museum-backcountry-skiing/marker-m-tour-ski/).